# Algorithm to recompute the shortest path after edge weight decreases

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Let d<sub>uv</sub> be the length of the shortest path from u to v in a directed graph. Suppose that the length of a single edge (x, y) decreases from c<sub>xy</sub> to c'<sub>xy</sub>. Design an algorithm to recompute all the d<sub>uv</sub>'s in O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 2):

Just set $d'_{u,v} = \min\{d_{u,v}, d_{u,x} + c'_{x,y} + d_{y,v}\}$ for all nodes $u$ and $v$. Since the number of pairs $(u,v)$ is in $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ and each minimum can be computed in constant time, this procedure has the desired runtime. The correctness follows by the fact that every shortest $u$-$v$-path in the modified network either uses edge $(x,y)$, then the shortest path will be shortened to $d_{u,x} + c'_{x,y} + d_{y,v}$, or it does not, then the shortest path length remains $d_{u,v}$.

Comment: The considered graph is directed. Thus, there might be an edge from $y$ to $x$ but the cost of this edge does not change.